# SQL Reporting Services, The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

A .net application works at a server which SQL Server 2005 , now we relocate the application to the new server which is SQL Server 2008.

Below is the error when I try to get a report from application:

> ### Server Error in '/Importal' Application.
>
> The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with
>   HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.]
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall) +431225
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) +204
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String
>   Report, String HistoryID) +69
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String
>   Report, String HistoryID) +67
>
> [MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server
>   failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server
>   is a compatible version.]
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.MissingEndpointException.ThrowIfEndpointMissing(WebException
>   e) +4027725
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String
>   Report, String HistoryID) +107
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo() +121
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) +67    ImportPerformanceKPI.btnList_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +425
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

Comment: Can you list the value of each item in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager Web Service URL pane?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure Reporting Services on your new SQL Server if it's not configured.
You've probably done that.

Inside the error, we have:

[MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. ]

Next make sure that your application is pointed at the new instance of SQL Server (it was looking for a 2005 instance).  And then check that your application will work with SSRS 2008.